# FOSElasticaBundle mapping array

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I try add mapped field to elastica

mapping config:

```
persistence:
                driver: orm
                model: PlaceBuundle\Entity\Place
                finder: ~
                provider: ~
                listener: ~

.....


                activePortals :
                      type: object
                      properties :
                          id:
                              type: integer
                  portalsSort:
                      type: object
                      properties:
                          id: ~
                          value: ~
```

in entity

```
public function getPortalsSort(){

        return array(
            array('id'=>1,'value'=>10)
        );

    }
```

error

```
 [Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\Exception\NoSuchPropertyException]                                       
  Cannot read property "id" from an array. Maybe you intended to write the property path as "[id]" instead.
```

there is no type: array

what is easiest way to map array values ?

Comment: Hey, mate did you find any solution please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use:

```
activePortals:
    type: nested
    properties :
        id:
            type: integer
```